# Vue, Vuex: Access private property in nested reactive class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

Given the following Vuex state:

```js
{
  model: new Model
}
```

The following Model:

```js
import { DataModel } from '@/foundation/data-model'
import { Child } from '@/models/child'

export class Model extends DataModel {
  static defaults = {
    name: null,
    child: new Child
  }

  constructor(payload = null) {
    super(Model.defaults)

    if (payload) this.hydrate({
      ...payload,
      child: new OtherModel(payload.child)
    })
  }
}
```

The child:

```js
import { DataModel } from '@/foundation/data-model'

export class Child extends DataModel {
  static defaults = {
    name: null
  }

  constructor(payload = null) {
    super(Child.defaults)
    this.hydrate(payload)
  }

  // other methods, setters, and getters.
}
```

And the DataModel:

```js
import { assign, cloneDeep } from 'lodash'

export class DataModel {
  #noHistory = false
  #originals = {}

  constructor(payload = null, noHistory = false) {
    this.#noHistory = noHistory
    this.hydrate(payload || {})
  }

  hydrate(payload = null, withOriginals = true) {
    if (!payload) return
    if (!payload instanceof Object) throw 'DataModel: payload is not an object'
    if (withOriginals && !this.noHistory) this.#originals = cloneDeep({ ...payload })

    assign(this, cloneDeep({ ...payload }))

    return this
  }

  get originals() {
    return this.#originals
  }

  // other getters and methods
}
```

Why is it that I am able to access `#originals` via `originals` in the root `model` (in Vuex state), but not `model.child.#originals` via `model.child.originals`?

If I attempt to do so, I get this:

> **TypeError:** attempted to get private field on non-instance

```js
model.originals // returns an object containing the original payload
model.child.originals // throws the TypeError
```

Is it perhaps due to the way in which Vue or Vuex wraps objects to make them reactive? If so, why would it apply only to `model.child` and not `model`, and how do I work around it?

Comment: please share the code of `Child` class

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim – it's a simple class that also extends DataModel and contains other properties and methods applicable to it. I've updated my question.

Comment: Additional note: as much as I'd love to know how to solve this problem, if anyone knows of a good model class that I can use instead of rolling my own, that too would be very helpful. It would need to be super simple, in that it need only track original attributes. I have tried a Proxy based approach, but that landed up not being viable…